# Последовательное выполнение функций

Tags: jquery

Хочу после анимации убрать блок со страницы. Т.е. сначала довести до opacity=0, потом сделать display=none

Код:

```
$("#go").click(function(){
  $("#block").animate({
    opacity: 0.0
  }, 500 );
  $("#block").hide();
});
```

сразу выполняет hide(), видимо параллельно. Как заставить выполнять последовательно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#go").click(function(){ 
    $("#block").animate(
        { opacity: 0.0 }, 
        500, 
        function(){
            $("#block").hide(); 
        } 
    );
});
```

или:

```
$("#go").click(function(){ 
    $.when( $("#block").animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 500) ).then(function(){ 
         $("#block").hide(); 
    });
});
```

кстате, `.animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 500)` эквивалентно `.fadeOut(500)`

- .animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] **[, complete]**): http://api.jquery.com/animate/
- [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)
- [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)
- [.fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: С when решение кривое

Comment: [факты](http://jsfiddle.net/TPsD4/) с вами не согласны